# Automatically find subsets in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, subset, combinations

I have a list of strings that contains strings consisting of just one word or multiple words separated by `,`. The list items are not unique and can be repeated in any possible combination. The list looks like this at the moment:

```
list = ['Car', 'Bed, Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Sofa, Pen, Car', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Car, Pen', 'Car']
```

Now, I want all possible subsets with a length of at least two (consecutive). However, I want combinations of STRINGS, not WORDS: A combination would be 'Car' and 'Bed, Car' but not 'Car' and 'Bed' because they don't appear consecutively.

I have not found a way to do this yet. Everytime I try to find subsets, the code focuses on words instead of entire strings...

Comment: what's the output example?

Comment: The output would be all consecutive combinations of two or more strings in the list, e.g.:
Car and Bed,Car
Bed,Car and Car
Car and House and Sofa,Pen,Car
...

Comment: I mean the complete output. Just like the list you gave:list = ['Car', 'Bed, Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Sofa, Pen, Car', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Car, Pen', 'Car']

Comment: There are many possible combinations, I cannot write them all down...

Comment: I got it. But you  can provide a smaller input so the output could be smaller too. Just take leecode description as example

Answer (score 1):

This may not be very Pythonic, but it works:

```py
my_list = ['Car', 'Bed, Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Sofa, Pen, Car', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Car, Pen', 'Car']
result = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(my_list) + 1):
        result += [my_list[i:j]]

print(result)
```

Comment: This throws an "unhashable type: 'slice'" error

Comment: @uwethebest123: it most definitely does not.

Comment: @gog Right, I used the wrong version of the list. The command does work but it does not what I want. As it says in the question, I want CONSECUTIVE combinations not just all random possible combinations

Comment: @uwethebest123: this is because your input is hard to follow. If you test this code with `['a', 'b', 'c']` the result will be `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: That is true but I wanted to emphasize that I have some strings that might seem as two separate ones but are in fact the same string

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `combinations` function from the `itertools` package

```
from itertools import combinations

my_list = ['Car', 'Bed, Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Sofa, Pen, Car', 'Pen', 'Pen', 'Car, Pen', 'Car']
my_set = set(my_list)
result = [comb for r in range(2, len(my_set)) for comb in combinations(my_set, r)]
```

This code makes a list of all possible unique combinations of at least two lengths.

Comment: That is true but by creating a set, I have unique values only which is not what I want. A possible unique consecutive series might also be Car,Car,Pen,Car where Car would appear multiple times

Comment: Then use `product` from the same `itertools` module

Comment: But keep in mind that the number of possible combinations grows exponentially. For example, for the input list you provided, the number of combinations will be 48427551 (all possible pairs, triplets, etc.)

Comment: result = [comb for r in range(2, len(my_list)) for comb in product(my_list, repeat=r)]

Comment: This is still not it. It gives all combinations but I need CONSECUTIVE ones

Comment: Okay, try using `combinations` as before, but don't convert the list to a set :)

Comment: result = [comb for r in range(2, len(my_list)) for comb in combinations(my_list, r)]

Comment: This is a little better as it does not give combinations of an element with itself but still combinations of non-consecutive elements in the original list

Comment: But it is a start because now, I can check if some elements of the new lists are subsets of the original list

Comment: I think it will be useful for you to get acquainted with the functionality provided by the following modules:
[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html);
[more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)